# TCP vs UDP for Initial World State

Tags: multiplayer, client-server, udp

I'm currently designing a fast paced multiplayer game with up to 6 concurrent players.

How should I send the client the initial world state from the server before the game starts? (such as the list of other players, and initial information about the map.)

I've chosen to use UDP for client input and world state updates - but I'm wondering if that protocol should also be used to send information that needs to be more reliable?

Comment: It sounds to me like you can answer this question for yourself. If you need reliability, then you either use a protocol that offers reliability out of the box, or you implement your own reliability layer on top of an unreliable protocol. Both routes get you to the same destination, the difference is in how friendly either one is to implement in your codebase, and you are a much greater expert on that than us strangers on the Internet.

Comment: You can develop a reliable transmission protocol based on udp, some open source projects have achieved this, such as [kcp](https://github.com/kcp-dev/kcp).

Comment: @DMGregory, yes I suppose I do know the answer to this. I might end up experimenting as well- I'll probably go with UDP first as most of that architecture is already designed. Just needed the push to go forward with this, Thank you!

Comment: @Mangata I will look into that as well. That will be helpful to see how they've implemented some things.

Comment: You may also want to check out [Glenn Fiedler's articles on networking](https://www.gafferongames.com/tags/networking/), particularly [his approach to implementing reliability](https://www.gafferongames.com/post/reliable_ordered_messages/).